# BAT File is not displaying the files it is copying

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

**EDIT :** **I can't add this as my answer for 8 hours so here is the answer on the post until I'm able to add it as an answer**

**"** *Doing a log both to CMD and to a logfile using Xcopy is not possible unless you use a workaround with a loop.
Instead, Robocopy is another way of managing copying to both CMD and a logfile and many more options.
[www.technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx](http://www.technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) 
Hopefully this helps anybody else with the same problem.* **"**

I'm trying to do a copy from one drive to the other while also showing in CMD the files that are being copied.

I've tried both /f and /l to show the files that are being copied however nothing changes.
What am I doing wrong?

```
echo
xcopy D:\home\website\*.* X:\WebsiteBackup /f /s /d /y /i > X:\WebsiteBackup\xcopy.log
```

I know the files are being copied due to the .log file as well as actually seeing the files go into my folder.

Comment: Are you aware that you are piping all output to the file?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Is it possible to do both a log and have it show in CMD?

Comment: I don't think you can do that (in a bat file) without grabbing each individual file and echoing it to the screen.  However, writing it in a Powershell script should make all of that easier.

Comment: I've found a different method via Robocopy that I'm going to try.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx Apparently it logs and echoes it to the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

A `TEE` filter is a tool that displays text on the screen and allows it to be logged to a file.

`Swiss File Knife` has a tee filter and is free.